# Add consecutive data to SHA256 without resetting the hash state

Tags: c#, .net-core, hash, sha

Are there any methods on C#'s `System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256` that allow me to submit a few byte arrays without reinitializing the SHA state every time? I.e. instead of

```cs
var lineBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(line);
var separatorByte = new[] { (byte) '|' };
var counterBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(counter.ToString());

var prehashBytes = new byte[lineBytes.Length + separatorByte.Length + counterBytes.Length];
lineBytes.CopyTo(prehashBytes, 0);
separatorByte.CopyTo(prehashBytes, lineBytes.Length);
counterBytes.CopyTo(prehashBytes, lineBytes.Length + separatorByte.Length);
                    
using var sha256 = SHA256.Create();
var hashed = sha256.ComputeHash(prehashBytes);
var hashString = Convert.ToHexString(hashed);
```

I'd like to be able to do

```cs
var lineBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(line);
var separatorByte = new[] { (byte) '|' };
var counterBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(counter.ToString());
                    
using var sha256 = SHA256.Create();
sha256.Advance(lineBytes);
sha256.Advance(separatorByte);
sha256.Advance(counterBytes);
var hashed = sha256.Hash;
var hashString = Convert.ToHexString(hashed);
```

yet there's no methods I can find on SHA256 that don't reset the hash state.

Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Part of the reason these hash functions are so great is because they operate on streams. (C#'s SHA256 class even provides a Stream-based method, but constructing a whole Stream for this would be overkill and not appropriate for the nature of my problem.)

Comment: [IncrementalHash Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.incrementalhash?view=net-6.0)?

Comment: IncrementalHash would be it :) Please make an answer if you'd like.

Comment: The `SHA256` class also has for this purpose the `TransformBlock` and `TransformFinalBlock` methods, which allow you to generate a hash from a sequence of consecutive byte arrays. But IncrementalHash is probably more convenient...